# Each elements by width

Tags: jquery

I can't find a solution.
How can I loop through all the elements starting from the one who has biggest width (in this case the elements with the class elname_03).

I have several div elements that have the same class name and I'm looping thru them.

Maybe there is a selector to do it?

```
<div class="el elname_01"></div>
<div class="el elname_03"></div>
<div class="el elname_02"></div>
<div class="el elname_03"></div>
<div class="el elname_02"></div>
<div class="el elname_03"></div>
```

- elname_01 - width 100px
- elname_02 - width 150px
- elname_03 - width 200px

I need to start checking from elname_03, after all they passed through the loop, then I need to loop all 02 numbers. I want to do this with one `each`, if it's possible, because I'm parsing data from json.

Comment: What do you mean by `to **each** all the elements`? Where is your code?

Comment: @VisioN I think he means "how to loop".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to sort jQuery object as array, and then iterate through it:

```
​var items = $('div');
Array.prototype.sort​​​​​​​​​.call(items, function(a,b){
    return b.offsetWidth - a.offsetWidth;
});

items.each(function() {
   console.log(this); 
});
```

Here's working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7BzH4/

Answer (score 0):

this is a guiding answer. it can be improved.

but this is the basic idea :

http://jsbin.com/aliqam/2/edit

```
<input class="a" style="width:10px";/>
  <input class="b" style="width:100px";/>
  <input class="c" style="width:40px";/>
```

```
function SortBySize(a, b)
{
    var aName = parseInt($(a).width());
    var bName = parseInt($(b).width());
    return((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

lets test :

before :

```
console.log($("input").eq(0).width())
console.log($("input ").eq(1).width())
console.log($("input").eq(2).width())

var gg = $("input").get().sort(SortBySize);
```

after :

```
console.log($(gg).eq(0).width())
console.log($(gg).eq(1).width())
console.log($(gg).eq(2).width())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get your div with biggest width:

```
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply( null, $('div.el').map( function () {
    return $(this).outerWidth( true );
}).get() );

alert(maxWidth);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UBdAS/